# Laravel join as array for json response

Tags: laravel, rest

maybe you can help me find out a query. I do a query Like

```
$Customers = Customer::paginate();
return response()->json([$Customers]);
```

this returns (just part of response)

```
[
    {       
        "current_page": 1,
        "data": [{"id": 1,}]
    }
]
```

If I do join with other table all data is just put into "data" output. What I want is this for my join: How to get this output??

```
    [
        {       
            "current_page": 1,
            "data": [{
                       "id": 1,
                       "join": [{ "join_column" : 1 }],
            }]
        }
    ]
```

Comment: Hi, you can achieve this with resources, have a look at the laravel documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-resources. But in here you can specify how you want your data to be returned.

Comment: Thanks! Forget about join, resources blow me away.